# How to input multiple data stored in different variables in one cell of a pdf using fpdf library and php

Tags: php, fpdf

How to input different strings in one cell when creating a pdf using fpdf?

Comment: Please insert code responsible for generating pdf document. Show some screenshots - improve your question if you want to get an answer :)

Comment: There is no code to it yet..I mean if you have one cell and you have 2 variables which both contain strings ...how do you insert both variables in that one cell